# AWS S3 with uploadify, how to restrict file types

Tags: uploadify, file-type

Under the scriptdata, in fileext how do I specify which file types are allowed?

eg:

```
$('#file_mainfile').uploadify({
        'uploader'  : '<?php echo WPDEPOSIT_URL; ?>/resources/js/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'script'    : '<?php echo $uploadPath; ?>',
        'cancelImg' : '<?php echo WPDEPOSIT_URL; ?>/resources/images/cancel.png',
        'folder'    : '<?php echo $fileFolder; ?>',
        'auto'      : true,
        'fileExt'   : '*.zip',
        'buttonText': '<?php _e('Upload .zip', WPD_SHOPPER_NAME); ?>',
        'method'    : 'post',
        <?php if(WPDS_AMAZONS3_ACTIVE == 'on'): ?>
        'fileDataName'  : 'file',
        'auto'          : 'true',
            'scriptData' : {
                "AWSAccessKeyId"                                : "<?php echo $amazonClass->AWS_ACCESS_KEY; ?>",
                "key"                       : "${filename}",
                "acl"                       : "public-read",
                "policy"                    : "<?php echo $policy; ?>",
                "signature"                 : "<?php echo $signature; ?>",
                "success_action_status"                         : "201",
                "key"                       : encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent("<?php echo $folder; ?>${filename}")),
/* here ---->  */    "fileext"                  : encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent("")),
                    "Filename"                  : encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(""))
                },
```

I actually already specified the allowed extensions; `'fileExt'   : '*.zip',`. But I can still upload other file types.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs, I have never had an issue using this syntax.  You are specifiying fileext when the syntax is fileTypeExts.

A list of allowable extensions that can be uploaded.  A manually typed in file name can bypass this level of security so you should always check file types in your server-side script.  Multiple extensions should be separated by semi-colons (i.e. ‘*.jpg; *.png; *.gif’).

http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/filetypeexts/

```
$(function() {
    $("#file_upload").uploadify({
        'fileTypeDesc' : 'Image Files',
        'fileTypeExts' : '*.gif; *.jpg; *.png',
        'swf'          : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader'     : '/uploadify/uploadify.php'
    });
});
```

Comment: looks like my uploadify is an older version. I'll update and hopefully this will be fixed.